Difficulty Understanding Notation for the Symmetries in Tiling Patterns
I am starting to learn group theory, and am reading about the symmetries in tiling patterns here. I have a few questions about the examples provided:

In figure 9, a vertical line through the red square is said to be a mirror line of symmetry. Doesn't this line flip the yellow and black parallelograms? Why is this considered a mirror line?
In figure 9 again, the group is labelled as "**" for the two mirror lines, but in figure 10, the two mirror lines (one horizontal and one vertical through the octagon's centre) are described by only one "*" in its label, "4*2". Why isnt it "**" in figure 10's label too?
Finally, am I correct in saying that a miracle is when you shift part of the tiling to create a new mirror line?


The colours are not part of the tilings.

A miracle does not involve shifting part of the tiling; if you flip the tiling in figure 14 along the line between the brown polygons, you can recover the original picture by shifting the whole tiling horizontally by the offset between the two rows of brown polygons. That symmetry is called a miracle.

Oh ok I think I get the miracle now, so if the flipped picture in some mirror line is the same as some translation of the original image, there is a miracle symmetry? Are there any restrictions on the translation, does it have to be horizontal or vertical only, or must it be parallel or perpendicular to the mirror line or can it be any translation?
